# Invalid object name 'App.fnSplit' with node.js and tedious

Tags: node.js, tedious

I'm using tedious to connect to SQL Server and run queries from node.js. One of my queries includes the following: `FROM App.fnSplit ('111,222,333,444', ',')`.

But it's throwing the following error: `Invalid object name 'App.fnSplit'`.

This works in the Java application that I'm converting to Node.js and also works from RazorSQL client. Is there any library that I need to include to get this working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give a try to sequelize node module. It MAY help you....

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? If so please mind sharing what was the solution